# Proposed deletion of tag [integrated]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

Currently there are 32 posts with the [integrated](/questions/tagged/integrated) tag; all seem to use "integrated" differently. Which is understandable, because the word "integrated" could be applied to just about anything that can be made part of a larger whole or placed within a broader context.

A sampling of the subject matter...

- [CakePHP and a central location for logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4587809/148680)
- [An ASP app that connects to SSRS and a SQL Server instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013766/148680)
- [Coaxial Switch Using Arduino and Multiplexers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10171443/148680)
- [Bindings for Tor in Python app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5414241/148680)
- [Integra**TION** testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767660/148680)

...and so on.

I understand that there's been [some concern](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136889/182807) that the [Great Stack Overflow Tag Cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315/182807) has thrown the baby out with the bath water, but I think this is a legitimate candidate for deletion.

Comment: FYI there are 32 such questions. 14 unanswered.

Comment: @Bart Thanks, good catch! Now I'm wondering if five examples is sufficient... Corrected the stated number.

Comment: Some seem related to IIS integrated mode (I have no idea what that is) and would maybe deserve their own tag?

Comment: @assylias
Do you mean that it might be worthwhile having an [iis-integrated] tag? Or that it might be worth keeping it as it is and, maybe, writing up a tag wiki?

Comment: @chb Not knowing what iis integrated is, I have no idea. Just thought it would be worth having a look at that one in particular.